# Animate textual changes in keynote

Tags: keynote, animation

I have some bullet points and I want to animate a change to some of them. For example:

- first bullet point
- the second one
- this is the third

Then I want the first to animate off the screen and be replaced by some different text, then the third one (the second one would stay the same).

Should I create a second set of bullet points representing the end-state and try to build it in as the other one builds out? Or split the bullets into separate objects? Or is there a way to animate text changes?

I also want to animate some similar text changes in non-bullet text (inserting/removing/changing words/lines) - can this be done easily or again would I need to somehow have two overlapping versions and animate one in and the other out simultaneously, or split the bits I want to move around into different objects?

I can figure out the details but I need some steer on the best overall approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the first bullet point to exit stage left, and have its replacement arrive from stage right. Then repeat wi point three.

Create each bullet point in its own text box. You can manually mimic the build in to match the rest of your presentation. Once the slide's build is complete, the easiest animation might be with a couple of additional slides set to Magic Move.

- slide 1, original text in place; bullet 1 replacement off screen
- slide 2, bullet 1 replacement in-line, original off screen, bullet 3 replacement off screen
- slide 3, bullet 3 original off screen, mullet 3 replacement in-line

If you're familiar with the Magic Move transition, this should make sense. If you're not accustomed to it, play and discover some fun!

Comment: It seems the best approach is to split everything into its own object. Thanks for the tip on MagicMove -  it's great, but it doesn't work on text very well (if anything changes that is not animatable - which is most things with text boxes - the shared instance of the object is converted into a separate object on the second slide).